# Remove code before <html> tag

Tags: php, openx

How would I delete all code or text before the `<html>` tag with a php code?

Asking because with OpenX no precaution of any kind seems to work, and injections keep turning up, but all before the `<html>` tag.

I tried this: $fullcode = strstr($fullcode, ''); to remove anything before `<html>`.
(And more that didn't work.)

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You've provided no source code, examples, what you've tried, nothing.

Comment: I tried this: $fullcode = strstr($fullcode, '<html>'); to remove anything before <html>.

Comment: @KJS What didn't work about that? It seems as if it should do what you're trying to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regexp with positive lookahead:

```
<?php
$html = "text before html<html>text after html";
$html = preg_replace('/^.*(?=<html>)/i', '', $html);
print $html;
```

Prints:

```
<html>text after html
```

Comment: This will usually work, but `<html>` can have attributes. Just removing `>` from the pattern would probably be enough.

Comment: Thanks! This works, however the injection is done somewhere else or otherwise. I added this code to OpenX anyway!